# How to execute an sql query in Crystal Reports 2008?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm able to connect Crystal Reports to the sql server and I can view the databases & tables inside the server. How can I execute an sql select statement from crystal reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute SQL statements directly (well, you can define fields, using direct SQL statements, but such fields make report structure messy). You should link needed tables on needed way; if you have more complex data structures, then it is often reasonable to create intermediate queries (views) or procedures in database and use them on report.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subreport and execute a query made in the main report.
Please, see this link below:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?546046-Dynamic-Crystal-Reports-Table-of-Contents-Index

It is usefull to create a Table Of Content in the main report.

Comment: Hello Bruno please include what the article says instead of just having a link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @SuitBoyApps, but it's a huge article because many steps must be done to get a Table Of Content on Crystal Reports...